# Putting CSS images into javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I want my css image to be used in javascript by an id.

CSS code:

```
#backImage {
    background-image: url("img/level1.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }
```

Javascript Code:

```
//Uploading obstacle car
var obstcar = new Image();
obstcar.src = $("#backImage").css;
```

Ask me any question and i will answer immediately.

This is how i drew my background:

```
context.drawImage(obstcar, -(obstcar.width / 2), -(obstcar.height / 2));
```

Comment: What do you mean with ` used in javascript by an id` ?

Comment: He wants to set obstcar to have an src of `#backImage` using js.  He didn't do any research clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be better to select by class and add that class to the image

```
.backImage {
    background-image: url("img/level1.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }
```

Javascript Code:

```
var obstcar = $("<image>").addClass('backImage')
```

Though thinking about it, Im not quite sure why an  `<img>` element would have a background image?

Maybe

```
var obstcar = $("<div>").addClass('backImage')
```

would be better

**Edit**

following your comment:

To create an the canvas you need an image object with the source attribute as the image

so lets make a temporary element and assign the css class to it

```
var tmp= $("<div>").addClass('backImage')
```

Then get the image source:

```
var src = tmp.css('background-image');
```

Create the image element

```
var obstcar = new Image();
obstcar.src = src
```

Get the context

```
var canvas=$("#myCanvas");
var ctx=canavas.getContext("2d");
```

Paint the canvas

```
ctx.drawImage(obstcar, -(obstcar.width / 2), -(obstcar.height / 2));
```

Comment: Hey andrew, the code you gave me is not working, maybe is because the way i drew my background. i updated the code on how i drew my background.

Comment: Andrew that was some really nice code and explanation.Unfortunately the code is not working. I am in high school and know nothing about programming and i can't do this by myself. So i made a fiddle so you can see all my code and see what is wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/ron9bv9q/

Comment: just looking at the fiddle

Comment: ok got it working, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r3cqomu8/) the trick was to remove `(url"` and `)"` from the `src` I did it with a regex, but i'm not very good with regular expressions so you should check its the best way

Comment: ok, seems to work every other time for some reason O_o prob somrthing to do with `$('document').ready` i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66783/discussion-between-the-good-guy-and-andrew).

Comment: so it turns out you need to use the image.onload event to update the canvas *after* the image loaded, updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lt5ynekq/